# Is the phrase 'do not take leave' the right way to convey the meaning?

Tags: sentence-construction, sentence-meaning, do-support

Can I use 'do not take leave' here?

> Mithilesh and me do not take leave this month.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If the 'month' is remaining 'won't take leave'. If it's over, 'did not take...'. 'don't take leave' better goes as a *command* as if your boss is telling both of you. "Mithilesh and Sagar, don't take leave this month'.

Comment: do you mean the part of the month that is past, or the part that is yet to come? It's possible that  "did not take",  or "are not taking" or "will not take" might be right.  In sny case, you need to say "_Mithilesh and I_"; not "Mithilesh and me".

Comment: @SugarPudi As Brian Hitchcock writes in his comment, you have many options, but it depends on your intended meaning. So, it'd better if you added more information about your context (in what occasion you're going to say that).

Comment: @BrianHitchcock That was a rather embarrassing mistake, thanks for helping me out :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the context is future tense...

First, correct 'Mithilesh and me' to 'Mithilesh and I'. (tip: Try the sentence without including Mithilesh, would you use Me or I?)

- Mithilesh and I will not take leave this month.
- Mithilesh and I will not take a leave of absence this month.
- Mithilesh and I will not go
  on leave this month.

The first example is more informal usage. The second adds the article ('a') and the type of leave, which would be a more rigorous or complete way to say this. The third is an alternative way of using the term leave in this context.

However, if you are simply trying to convey that you and Mithilesh will be on duty for the entire month, you may wish to state that, as there are other reasons that you may be absent during the month.

Answer (score 0):

According to my context,

> Mithilesh and I will not take the leave this month.

Thanks for help

Comment: If you don't use coding type of formatting (I'm not sure how it's called) posts are easier to read :-). You can answer your own questions (like you just did) but you can also edit your post to add context (or better yet write as much information about your question as you can, right away) and then have more comprehensive replies posted as answers, which will benefit not just you, but future users of the website as well ;-)

Comment: Perhaps "_a_ leave"?